# I'm afraid I don't understand these lines, can you please help me

Tags: word-meaning

When I happened to be reading [this article,](https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/john-oliver-last-week-tonight-023812613.html) 
I encountered 2 phrases ( or probably 4 words ) which I don't understand correctly.

It saying,

> Once again Oliver delivered a charming, brief acceptance speech, noting he’s brought his entire staff to the Emmy ceremony as they **hollered from the nose-bleed seats,** ( A ) and **asked to be played off.** ( B )
>
> After which Kimmel and Colbert – both ( C ) **nommed** in the category this year

I scraped the line and marked as ( A ) ( B ) ( C ) so that it could look clearer.

And my question is..

( A ) Am I correct that the ( A ) means the Kimmel's staff were grumbling or 
      murmuring from expensive seats or some kind of that sort?

( B ) What does the phrase "play off" mean here?

( C ) Am I correct to understand that ( C ) denoted Kimmel and Colbert were
      nominated ( I am afraid I was not able to find any proper entry in the
      dictionaries. )

Again, thank you so much for the help

Thank you.

Sincerely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "nose-bleed seats" (for example in a large stadium) are those at or near the top, high up. It is a form of exaggeration. The altitude is so high that your nose bleeds. They are the least expensive seats.

To be **played off** is to have the band play music as you leave the stage.

The ushers "see someone off the stage" and the band "plays someone off the stage".

To see s.o. off, to play s.o. off.  Transitive phrasal verb.  Thus, **to be played off** is a passive infinitive construction, complement of **asked**. He asked *to be played off* [the stage] (by the band).

**nommed** is show-biz argot for **nominated**.